# UPDATE TABLE with count

Tags: sql, sql-update, informix

I have some trouble with UPDATE
i use posgress in informix DB
I have two table.

1-st table with call data (anslogin, grade_1, grade_2, grade_3, grade_4, grade_5)
2-nd data with agent id and count of grade for every  agents there group by logins ID.
I created 1-st table and copy there all logins ID from 2-nd table.

And then I want create another 5 request for every grade (1,2,3,4,5) but i have trouble with UPDATE:

```
UPDATE grade a
    SET (grade_1) = (SELECT count(lastdigigts)
FROM call_rec b WHERE a.anslogin = b.anslogin
AND lastdigits ='1')
```

I don't think so that idea with five request is good but another i can't see may be you see another way to resolve my task

tables for best understanding:
1-st table

```
| login | grade_1 | grade_2 | grade_3 | grade_4 | grade_5 |
| Ivan  |    2    |   3     |    4    |    1    |  null   |
| Masha |    1    |   3     |    4    |    null |  4      |
| Kolya |    5    |  null   |    4    |    1    |  null   |
```

2-nd table

```
|anslogin|lastfigits|
|Kolya   |       2  |
|Ivan    |       2  |
|Kolya   |       2  |
|Kolya   |       2  |
|Kolya   |       2  |
|Masha   |       2  |
|Ivan    |       2  |
```

Comment: " i use posgres in informix DB" this doesn't make sense.  Are you saying that you have a linked informix table in your Postgres database?

Comment: yes,  i'm work with informix database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use 5 correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE grade g
    SET grade_1 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '1'),
        grade_2 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '2'),
        grade_3 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '3'),
        grade_4 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '4'),
        grade_5 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '5');
```

Note that I changed the table aliases to meaningful abbreviations rather than arbitrary letters.

In Postgres, you could simplify this to:

```
UPGRADE grade g
    SET grade_1 = cr.grade_1,
        grade_2 = cr.grade_2,
        grade_3 = cr.grade_3,
        grade_4 = cr.grade_4,
        grade_5 = cr.grade_5
    FROM (SELECT anslogin,
                 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE lastdigits = '1') as grade_1,
                 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE lastdigits = '2') as grade_2,
                 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE lastdigits = '3') as grade_3,
                 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE lastdigits = '4') as grade_4,
                 COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE lastdigits = '5') as grade_5
          FROM call_rec cr
          GROUP BY anslogin
         ) cr
    WHERE cr.anslogin = g.anslogin;
```

Comment: it's look like a mistake is it correct FROM call_rec cr
          GROUP BY anslogin cr
         ) ??

Comment: @OlegDuplenko . . . The code `FROM call_rec cr GROUP BY anslogin cr )` is not in this answer.  The code looks correct to me.

Comment: And if i used 1-st version a have error: convert a character to numeric conversion process failed. Origin table with lastdigits have a character type, grade_1 i'm created with character type too

Comment: @OlegDuplenko . . . I added the quotes back in.  When something looks like a number, I tend to assume that it is.

Comment: I try to execute request: Syantax error occured, in editor i can't see that FILTER looks like service word

Comment: @OlegDuplenko . . . The second query is explicitly only for Postgres.  You didn't include Informix on the tags, so it seemed reasonable to assume you were using Postgres.  Fix the tags on the question.

Comment: sorry, thank's for correction i'm new on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

THIS variant is workes!!!!

```
UPDATE grade g
    SET grade_1 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = r.anslogin AND lastdigits = '1'),
        grade_2 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '2'),
        grade_3 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '3'),
        grade_4 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '4'),
        grade_5 = (SELECT count(*) FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = cr.anslogin AND lastdigits = '5');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worked.

```
UPDATE grade
    SET (grade_1,grade_2,grade_3,grade_4,grade_5) = (
    (
    SELECT 
    sum(case when lastdigits = '1' then 1 else 0 end) 
    ,sum(case when lastdigits = '2' then 1 else 0 end) 
    ,sum(case when lastdigits = '3' then 1 else 0 end) 
    ,sum(case when lastdigits = '4' then 1 else 0 end) 
    ,sum(case when lastdigits = '5' then 1 else 0 end) 
    FROM call_rec cr WHERE g.anslogin = r.anslogin
    )
);
```